# Truffle Contract sendTransaction not immediately returning transaction hash

Tags: truffle-contract, sendtransaction, async

I am using Truffle Contract to call a Smart Contract method that writes to the ethereum blockchain. My web3 client is connected to my own Open Ethereum node. Below is the code (nodejs) that I am using to send the transaction to blockchain. I would expect, since this is an asynchronous call that the response would be immediately and the transaction hash value would be returned. However, this is NOT happening. The only time I get a response is after the transaction is mined. I can't rely on this because my front-end client will time out (30 secs for AWS API Gateway). What am I doing wrong? I can see all the eth_getTransactionReceipt json calls in my OE log, being called back to back until the transaction is mined.

async function sendTransClaimProperty(_instance) {

```
    var result;
    
    try {
      
      result = await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.defaultAccount, process.env.oranges, null);
      console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount + " Account UnLocked", result);
      
      if (result) {
            var claimState = "Property Claimed on " + new Date();
            console.log("Calling Ethereum Node at " + new Date());
            
            result = await _instance.claimProperty.sendTransaction(claimTitle,claimHash,claimTime,claimCreditCardTx,claimClientIP,claimState);
                
            console.log("Return from Ethereum Node result", result);
            console.log("Return from Ethereum Node. TX", result.tx);
            return { response: "OK", transHash: result.tx };
            
      } 
    }
    catch (error) {
      
      console.log("Error Sending Transaction");
      console.log(error.message);
      return { response: "FAIL", message: "Error claiming property " + error.message };
      
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the transaction hash without waiting you have to use the events system

```
const res = _instance.claimProperty(claimTitle,...);
res.on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
  console.log('TxHash', hash);
});
```

You will find some other details at [Truffle reference](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions).

Comment: Ismael, Thanks for the advice. It did not work. The response from the async call returned this  

INFO Response is Promise {
  <pending>,
  _events: Events <[Object: null prototype] {}> {},
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners]

This async call however, is part of a synchronous function call. Maybe that's the problem. 
I will continue to try

Comment: @KevinMelberger What did you try? and why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: I added the event emitter code, but it does not work. Everything I tried will not get me back the transaction hash BEFORE the transaction is mined. Code example below:          _instance.claimProperty.sendTransaction(claimTitle,claimHash,claimTime,claimCreditCardTx,claimClientIP,claimState)
                  .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                         txHash = hash;
                         console.log("Return from Ethereum Node. TX ", hash);
                      })
                   .on('error',console.error);